# Freud defense mechanisms combinations with jung Anima/animus archetype

Tags: jung, freud

In correlation between carl jung for famous archetypes like the Self, the Persona, the Shadow and the Anima/Animus, and Freud defense mechanism, are done any tracking human sexual algorithms and its upgrading or downgrading?

For example in adult pornography behaviors and thus the reactions which downgrading or upgrading, could we  classifying these in Freud's defense mechanism levels that change the user's Anxiety and stress, with. Combination this classification by  looking into Jung anima and animus developments growing and downgrading levels?

If not is there any paper on discussion via internet, or ... and which discussed about correlation between those (Freud defence mechanism and Jung archetype. Anima/animus growing levels ?

***Update:***

i am looking somethings like [this](https://www.slideshare.net/LouiseBangor/freuds-psychosexual-stages-and-defence-mechanisms):

[image]

but in correlation about Freud defense mechanism with Jung, archetypes (specially anima and animus) also better for describing the levels of growing for example the growing levels of anima which is [this kind](https://psychology.wikia.org/wiki/Anima_and_animus) :

[image]

Thanks for your attention to this hard question.

Comment: I am sorry but I am having problems understanding what you are asking about. Can you try and provide a bit more on what you are talking about? Maybe some web links to related material may help. Whilst [I am a defender of Freudian and Neo-Freudian psychology](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2248), please also be aware that this covers areas of psychology [considered by some here to be pseudoscientific](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2242)

Comment: @Chris_Rogers i have updated the question, is it clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any paper on discussion via internet, or ... and which discussed about correlation between those (Freud defence mechanism and Jung archetype. Anima/animus growing levels?

Elements of your question discusses 3 very different theories which do not correlate directly with each other.

Yes, Jung came up with the different levels of development for the anima and animus, but this is very different to Freud's [Psychosexual Stages of Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychosexual_development) which is briefly covered in your image.

Neither of these theories correlate with each other and neither correlate at all with Freud's [Defense Mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_mechanism) as they have nothing to do with development, although they can affect development.

There are many different theories of development which some are discussed in my answer at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/17211/7604. If all these theories are taken on board together, they can form an integrative theory of human development, but where some are similar, some differ greatly.